# How to check in C Posix thread if someone is waiting on a shared semaphore?

Tags: c, multithreading, semaphore, solaris-10

This is for exception handling scenario in a multi-threaded scenario. More than one threads are working in parallel on some shared resource locked under mutual exclusion whenever needed. If one thread faces an exception, can  I use sem_trywait to  check if some other thread is waiting on the semaphore and if I find some thread is waiting on a semaphore, will use a flag that exception has occurred and I will issue a sem_post so that waiting thread may unwait and check if some exception occurred before proceeding further. In case exception occurred, the other thread which was otherwise waiting will now proceed towards a graceful exit. Please suggest.
My actual qs is: can I use sem_trywait?

Comment: What's your actual question?

Comment: @ammoQ, can I use sem_trywait to check ...?

Comment: All that would do is either obtain the semaphore or not.  It doesn't tell you if anyone is waiting for it.

Comment: @wallyk if I could obtain the semaphore in one thread, doesn't that imply that no one else was waiting? Or any other way to know?

Comment: No, you do not *obtain* a semaphore. You just *wait* for it. More than one process can wait for a semaphore, but with each sem_post, just one of them is awakened.

Comment: @Dr.DebasishJana *if I could obtain the semaphore in one thread, doesn't that imply that no one else was waiting?* It just means your thread successfully waited on the semaphore.  Even if you call `sem_post()` on that semaphore, a successful `sem_trywait()` does **not** mean there's no other tread waiting on the semaphore.

Comment: If you know that an exception has happened, why don't you release the locked resources instead of setting a flag to say an exception happened?

Answer (score 2):

The most straightforward solution would be to set up an additional mechanism of thread status.  Semaphores are not intended to indicate whether anyone is waiting for them.

In a globally visible variable which is only written by the thread, set it to—say `1`—if some thread is waiting for the semaphore and `0` if not.  If anyone wants to know if the thread is wanting to obtain the semaphore, check the state of the variable.  It shouldn't be too difficult to handle race conditions sampling the variable by ordering operations correctly.